# How to get client username using angular js / java scipt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, windows-authentication

I am developing an intranet app and I have enabled windows authentication in IIS server.
Now when the client opens my intranet app I want know the username of the windows machine (currently logged in windows username )

How can I accomplish this with angular.js?  (or plain JS if necessary)